# python control audio speed

Tags: python, audio

Let me introduce my problem. I've got an audio file, call it *audio_file*, and a function *audio_speed* which takes as input an instant time t, and return a real number which will be interpreted as a speed. I want to realize a python program such that:

- at each time t, audio_file's speed execution is equal to audio_speed(t);

So at time t, I compute audio_speed(t) and then reproduce the audio_file at speed audio_speed(t) for a small period of time, say t+delta_t. Roughly speaking, I want to control the audio speed in real time. I've search on the internet but I didn't find something comprehensible.

Do you know what kind of python's instruments I can use to fix the above described problem?

Please, help me.

Comment: Post your code or else your question will just be downvoted to oblivion

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what kind of libraries I need to use in order to solve the problem. In fact, my question is all about: do you know what kind of python's instruments I can use to fix the above described problem?

Comment: If audio is realtime, look for `pyaudio` blocking callback feature, see here  https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#wire-example and if its offline (from a file) you can try `pydub` , see here https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/effects.py